# Add a KeyListener to a Thread

Tags: java, awtrobot

I created a program that using the Robot class to output some text on my notepad.

```
public class Main extends Thread implements KeyListener {

  public Main() {
     addKeyListener(this);
     ...
  }
```

I would like to stop it by clicking on a certain key, is it possible? I tried to implement it and add it but it's a compilation error.

My class is a sub-class of Thread.

Comment: "*I tried to implement it and add it but it's a compilation error.*" => in that case, showing your code would certainly help...

Comment: public class Main extends Thread implements KeyListener .... on the constructor I tried: addKeyListener(this) which is a compilation error

Comment: please edit your question and add the Codes in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> public class Main extends Thread implements KeyListener {

If you look at the [javadoc for the Thread class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), you will see that it doesn't contain the `addKeyListener` method, hence the compilation error.

Note, however, when using `java.awt.Robot` you are concerned about *issuing* `KeyEvents` rather than listening for them:

```
Robot robot = new Robot(); 
 // Create a delay of 5 sec so that you can open notepad 
robot.delay(5000);
robot.keyPress(...);
```

**Edit:** To exit, you could emulate the key combination `ALT`+`F4`.

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);  
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F4);  
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);  
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
```

Note the key release commands. This is necessary to disengage the key state from the previous key combination.

Comment: I will accept your answer when it will be possible, in the mean time do you have an idea how I can implement it?setting some kind of a listener? I mean I'm looking for a way to shut down the program by the  keyboard